# vba ADODB cmd.execute run oracle stored procedure problem

Tags: vba, oracle, stored-procedures, adodb

I use the following VBA code trying to run an **oracle stored procedure**. The connection is defined in another `Sub` as `Oracon` and success.

I use ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 6.0 Library and ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library

I tested the following line and it works:

```vb
Sql = "SELECT distinct currency_code FROM sets_of_books;"

recset.Open Sql, Oracon, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset recset
```

But when I tried to call stored procedure, I run into problems.

```vb
Sub Call_Procedure()

Dim Oracon As ADODB.Connection
Dim recset As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim parm1 As New ADODB.Parameter
Dim parm2 As New ADODB.Parameter
Dim parm3 As New ADODB.Parameter
Dim parm4 As New ADODB.Parameter


Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

cmd.ActiveConnection = Oracon
cmd.CommandText = "My_stored_Procedure"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

Set parm1 = cmd.CreateParameter("p_set_of_book_id", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, "20213")
cmd.Parameters.Append parm1

Set parm2 = cmd.CreateParameter("p_account_id", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, "58888")
cmd.Parameters.Append parm2
Set parm3 = cmd.CreateParameter("p_date_from", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, "2022/01/01 00:00:00")
cmd.Parameters.Append parm3
Set parm4 = cmd.CreateParameter("p_date_to", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, "2022/01/31 00:00:00")
cmd.Parameters.Append parm4

Set recset = cmd.Execute  'This line shows this problem

write_results_to_sheet recset   'another procedure used to store the returns of recset

recset.Close

End Sub
```

the debug line is this :

```vb
Set recset = cmd.Execute
```

The error message is:

> Run-time error '3709' The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context.

I also tried these ways, but it also don't work:

```vb
recset.Open cmd, , adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

```vb
recset.Open cmd, Oracon, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

Comment: Do you actually set `Oracon` in the code, i cant see it?

Comment: yes. I set in another VBA Sub procedure

Comment: But you declare it a *local* variable. If you set it in another procedure, either declare it as global or change the procedure as function and return the connection object.

Comment: yea. Thanks, man. I put the Call_Procedure into the Connection procedure. It seems worked when F8 to the line `Set recset = cmd.Execute`. But now the problem is Excel crashes ... any ideas? –

Comment: Does your stored procedure actually return a recordset?

Comment: Hi Tim, yea. I think so. the oracle stored procedure output is  fnd_file.put_line. Then the ebs convert it to html.

Comment: This is the output:  fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.output,
                      cur1.*** || chr(9) ||cur1.***|| chr(9) || cur1.*** || chr(9) ||
                      cur1.***) . cur1 returns the main sql result.